# Validity of the Schengen visa when having a residence sticker in the passport (The Netherlands)

Tags: schengen

I had a Dutch residence permit which expired this year. I applied for the change of purpose of stay to get a new one. In the meantime, I got a residence sticker (VAA, or Verblijfsaantekeningen). My application was recently rejected. I'm going to file an appeal, and while it is processed I can legally stay in NL and get another sticker in the passport. This sticker confirms my right to stay in the country but doesn't allow me to enter the Schengen area if I leave it.

In addition to that, I have a long-term multi-entry Schengen tourist visa Type C issued in 2015 or so, which expires in November this year, so technically it is still valid. But I was shocked by an employee at the IND (Dutch migration authority) who said that this visa became automatically invalid when I got a residence sticker! She added that if a border officer saw the sticker in addition to my Schengen visa, they would refuse my entry. Couldn’t get any reference to laws/bylaws from her.

Another day I asked a different IND employee and explained the whole situation. He was surprised about the supposition that the visa became void. Then he consulted someone and returned back a bit confused saying that the situation was unclear and depended on the specific officer (!) who checks my passport at the border, so he couldn’t say for sure whether the visa is automatically cancelled or still valid, and what would happen to me at the passport control.

Could someone comment on this topic? Is the visa valid until the stated date of expiration, or such stickers in the passport invalidate it automatically? Obviously, I tried to google but my situation seems to be not very typical…

Comment: Are you sure they weren't trying to tell you that it depends on which *country's* officer checks your passport at the border (that is, on where you try to enter the Schengen area)?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! The first lady said: "Your visa is not valid any more, now you have a sticker". The second guy said the decision to allow/reject depended on a specific officer, meaning how they understand the laws, not the country of entrance.